# How to register multiple apps models in a admin.py file

Tags: python, django-models, django-admin

I have three app in my project first app does not have any model while the the second app has two models which have been registered in admin site as given bellow.

**admin.py for second app:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Country, CountryDetails

admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(CountryDetails)
```

My third app has another model and I want to register its model in the admin site of second app, how can I do this.

I have tried this, Though I don't know wither its a right way to do it or not but its not working.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Country, CountryDetails
from thirdapp.models import Model_of_my_third_app

admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(CountryDetails)
admin.site.register(Model_of_my_third_app)
```

showing an Error

```
Django “No Module Named URLs” error
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After struggling little bit I am able to figure out the problem, Actually  I din't  create  a "urls.py" files for my  "thirdapp", while I had included the given line:

```
url(r'', include('fastaapp.urls')),
```

Into myproject urls.py file, hence I have to create a "urls.py" file within a new app with a minimum content  like this:

```
urls.py for "thirdapp" should be like this

from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

]
```